# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'value' PYTHON TO EXCEL

Tags: excel, for-loop, openpyxl, attributeerror, python-3.8

I am currently trying to write data to an excel spreadsheet using Python3 and openpyxl. I have figured out how to do it when assigning one single value, but for some reason when I introduce a For loop it is giving me an error. This program will eventually be used to filter through a python dictionary and print out the keys and values from the python dictionary. For now, I am just trying to create a loop that will input a random integer in the spreadsheet for every key listed in the dictionary (not including nested keys). If anyone can help me determine why this error is coming up it would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
# Writing Dictionary to excel spreadsheet
import openpyxl
import random

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("ExampleSheet.xlsx")
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name("Sheet1")

sheet["B1"].value = "Price" #This works and assigns the B1 value to "price" in the spreadsheet

my_dict = {'key': {'key2' : 'value1', 'key3' : 'value2'} 'key4' : {'key5' : 'value3', 'key6' : 'value4'}} #an example dictionary

n = len(my_dict)
  for i in range(0,n): 
    sheet['A'+ str(i)].value = random.randint(1,10) #This does not work and gives an error

wb.save('ExampleSheet.xlsx')

OUTPUT >>> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'value'
```

Comment: use `ws.iter_rows(min_col=1, max_col=1)` to avoid these kind of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first column of pyxl, is one based, so if you modify your loop to go over range(1,n) your issues should be resolved

Comment: That's it! Thank you

Comment: hm, looks like `ws['A0']` returns a column rather than raising an exception. This is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Using `.format(i)` instead of `string + str(i)` in ur code may work well!

BTW, ur var `my_dict` get an error .

eg:

```
for i in range(10):
    sheet['A{}'.format(i)].value = 'xx'
```